# CKEditor: capturing on paste event (including Shift + Insert)

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, dom-events, internet-explorer-9, copy-paste

We are using CKEditor and we are handling the paste event like such:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.OurInputControlName;
editor.on('paste', function(ev) {
    alert('we are in the on paste event!');
}
```

However, I have just discovered that users are able to paste by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> and our paste event handler is not being executed.

How can I add an event handler that captures <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> and pasting.

We're on CKEditor 4.1.1.

**Edit:**
This might be an IE only problem, IE9 at least. I am yet to try other versions of IE. It works fine in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue by detecting when <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> was pressed in IE and manually firing the paste event.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.OurInputControlName;
editor.on('key', function(ev) {
    if (ev.data.keyCode == 2228269 && $.browser.msie) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var event = {
                'type': 'html',
                'dataValue': editor.getData()
            };
            editor.editable().setHtml('');
            editor.fire('paste', event);
        }, 100);
    }
});
editor.on('paste', function(ev) {
    alert('we are in the on paste event!');
}
```

I am using `setHtml()` as calling `editor.setData('')` kept logging a Javascript error in the console (even though it did seem to clear the textarea and did not stop the page working).